# How do I maximize my IP boost?

Tags: league-of-legends

Because League of Legends was voted lord of the flies or something, all its saprophytic users have apparently been given a 10-win IP boost.

How does the IP boost work?  How can I get the best use out of it; just play 5v5 games, or is there no difference between the game types?

Comment: Saprophytic:  Any organism that lives on dead organic matter, such as certain fungi and bacteria.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per-win IP boosts (the kind most often given out for free) *do not* change in value based on the length of the game. Do not intentionally draw out winning games (and thereby risk losing those games) in the mistaken belief you will net additional IP.

Per-time IP boosts double the base IP gained for all games played, which is a function of game length, but per-win boosts reward a constant value on each victory, which varies with game type.

**A per-win boost will always award:**

- **145 IP for 5v5 (PvP) game on Summoner's Rift**,
- 96 IP for Howling Abyss,
- 74 IP for a Co-op vs. AI game.

I don't know the Crystal Scar or Twisted Treeline values, but I've been led to believe that they are each less than PvP Summoner's Rift, but more than vs. AI Summoner's rift.

In short, the way to maximize a per-win IP boost is to exhaust the boost on Summoner's Rift before you play Dominion, Treeline, or especially Co-op vs. AI.

Comment: +1 : I was wondering how previous answers could be correct when I always had 145 IP bonus.

Answer (score 3):

The way the IP boost works is by multiplying your regular IP gain from winning games.

This particular boost applies to ten wins.  Loses do not negatively affect this boost in any way.

First win of the day adds a flat bonus that is applied independently of this calculation.  The best way to maximize your IP gain is to play 5v5 games against players (Verses computer games give you less IP). You'll get a higher boost the longer the game goes, so if you have friends that play you may find it beneficial to try out all-tank teams.  Again, losing costs you nothing but time.

Speaking of time, playing Dominion games may be faster, but beware: You will get less out of your bonus for doing so.

Comment: Spot on.  Maximize your IP with PvP games that are long.  To that end, don't smash the other team too early or they'll surrender at 20. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Per Win Boosts provide an extra 145 Influence Points on Summoner's Rift and are a great way to farm Influence Points (provided you have the Riot Points!).

If you are after more information check out this [LoL - Influence Point Guide](http://www.squidoo.com/league-of-legends-ip-hack)

Answer (score -1):

It works by multiplying your regular ip gain from winning games (not the "first win of the day" - bonus if my memory serves me right) so yes, therefor your best bet to maximize it is playing long 5v5 games.

Remember to loose (or leave if it's just you in the game) vs bots and such if you're just playing to try out a new character.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Though unorthodox, I like the idea of intentionally losing to bot games to preserve your IP boost.