# Increasing the amount of IP gained from battles

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the Co-op vs AI IP award system work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18485/how-does-the-co-op-vs-ai-ip-award-system-work)
>   [How much IP do you get for winning & losing games in the various modes/maps?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/how-much-ip-do-you-get-for-winning-losing-games-in-the-various-modes-maps)

Aside from the first win of the day (+150 IP), generally, the IP gained from a battle is opaque -- you have no idea if it's due to anything other than victory or defeat.

What are the ways to increase IP earned from battles? I've heard that it depends on the game duration (and I've seen a correlation of *n* IP gained for a game of *n - 1* minutes). Is that all? Is that accurate? What else is out there?

Comment: The answer for IP gain can be found here: [How does the Co-op vs AI IP award system work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18485/how-does-the-co-op-vs-ai-ip-award-system-work). Also [related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33308/how-do-i-maximize-my-ip-boost) and [related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60237/fastest-way-to-farm-ip-general-assumptions-inside).

Comment: Also related: [How much IP do you get for winning & losing games in the various modes/maps?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29606/3107)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IP are gained linearly by length of the match, with influences including but not limited to your first win in the last 22 hours, winning or losing the match, and any IP boosts you may have active at the time of joining the game. More details will follow with edits.

> > There is minimum and maximum reward for game length.

- On *Summoner's Rift* these cap at 25 and 55 minutes respectively. (76 IP for a win @ 25 and 145 IP for a win @ 55)
- On *Twisted Treeline* the minimum is 20 minutes with a 64 IP gain for a win. The maximum is listed as unknown on the wiki.
- Ranked games have a different cap, wiki states that it might be 65 minutes with a 168 IP gain on a win.
- The Formulae listed says *Wins* give (18 + 2.312 IP per minute) and *Losses* give (16 + 1.404 IP per minute).
- Custom games grant 50% of normal IP. Unbalanced games (2v3, etc) do not give IP.
- Custom games grant further penalties depending on your summoner level, and have a cap of 180 minutes in a 22 hour period where they stop giving IP to summoners above level 15.

More information and details can be found at the [source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Influence_Points)

Comment: Note: This math does not work for dominion, it's different `Formula: { [base IP] + ([IP / min] * [game time in minutes]) * [gamemode modifier] } + [Dominion Bonus]` ------ `Dominion has a special bonus that is given depending on how well your team did. The more hp you nexus has if you win the larger the bonus, the less hp their nexus has if you lose the larger your bonus.`

Comment: @Michel Ayres That is correct, but it's in the source, and I didn't think it would've been good to practically copy\paste the wiki, so I put in the source link

Comment: @Ender no problem, but try cover all variables when possible, if you don't wanna explain one part because is too long or may generate discussion, you can inform that in your answer, and why you are avoiding it. So people will understand it. We **usually** ask for "copy/paste" part of the source, to don't be mandatory the user enter in the link to obtain the answer.

Comment: Also, worth noting that per-win and daily ip boosts stack.

Comment: @MichelAyres Ok thanks, good to know. Assuming you've read the source, should I at least annotate through edit everything that I have so far left completely out then?